# Finding a record based on range of date

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I am quite new to SQL. Basically I have a database with a column named "Date", and I want to return all the entries such that "Date" is between `startDate` and `endDate`

```
Dim myStr As String = String.Format("Select * from {0} where [Date] between @date1 and @date2", databaseTableName)

Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter(myStr, sqlConn)

ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", frm.StartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", frm.EndDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

where `frm` is a Windows Form date time picker.

Not sure where I went wrong but the query does not return anything at all.

Comment: You're supposed to be passing dates in the query and you call `ToString`.  DO NOT convert a binary `Date` value into a `String`.  If what you actually want to do is to zero the time then that's what you do, i.e. use `frm.StartDate.Value.Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim myStr As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE [Date] >= @date1 AND < @date2", databaseTableName)

Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter(myStr, sqlConn)

ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date1" SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = frm.StartDate.Value.Date
ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = frm.EndDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set 'dd/MM/yyyy', SQL will return error 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a DateTime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.' I think you should set format as below.

```
ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", frm.StartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", frm.EndDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
```

Comment: If you're using a string to set a date value for a query at all, you're still doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Why can not use string to set date value, my friend? It's example: select top 10 FirstName, ModifiedDate
 from Person.Person
 where ModifiedDate between '2009/01/10' and '2009/01/20'

Comment: Several reasons. One is that the server might actually have a different date format you expect. It's all fun and games until you get a customer in Germany, or someone picks the wrong region for an Azure instance. Another reason is [performance](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn. Ok, I got it. Your solution is great. Thanks :)